# Spring 3 HelloWorld Program

Tags: java, spring

I am currently attempting to get a spring program up and running. I am using [this](http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring3/spring-3-hello-world.shtml) example to teach me how to do it. I have done everything the example has says, except when I attempt to run it in step 12, I get an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [SpringHelloWorld.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [SpringHelloWorld.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:78)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:66)
at net.roseindia.Spring3HelloWorldTest.main(Spring3HelloWorldTest.java:12)
```

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [SpringHelloWorld.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 4 more

I am really new to spring so I don't really know what's happening. I know in my class I attempt to import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;, but I think that is what is throwing the error or causing it not to work.

If anybody knows what went wrong, or a better Spring example that is easy to follow it would be much appreciated.

Morgan

Answer (score 1):

Put that XML file in your CLASSPATH.  The Bean Factory can't find your configuration file.

You do that using the -cp option to java.exe:

```
java -cp .;<individual-jars>;<directory-where-xml-config-lives> Spring3HelloWorldTest
```